# Подключить библиотеки d

Tags: c#, dll

если нужно сразу подключить все библиотеки которые находятся в одной папке ?То есть закинул 3 dll , они автоматом подключились , закинул ещё 5 , они подключились. Как это реализовать программно ?

Comment: что значит "забросил - подключились"? Как планируются использоваться эти библиотеки?

Comment: Ведём проект  на виртуалке . Есть папка куда помещаем библиотеки сторонние из Nuget. По мере работы добавляем новые библиотеки . Что б в процессе работы , не подключать библиотеки вручную , делать ссылки и тд. Просто программно подключить библиотеки

Comment: Так а в чём смысл-то? Что значит "подключились"? Куда как для чего подключились?

Comment: @Snaky а чем вам непосредственно nuget-то не угодил? Зачем вам вручную закидывать куда-то библиотеки?

Comment: народ, вопрос-то зачем закрыли? Он же совершенно понятный, "подключение библиотеки"-общеизвестный термин...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается средствами msbuild.

Откройте ваш файл проекта (который с расширением .csproj) и добавьте туда следующие строки:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="путь\к\папке\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

---

Однако, у меня есть ощущение, что таким образом вы пытаетесь обойти отсутствие доступа к интернету, мешающее загружать пакеты из репозитория nuget стандартными средствами.

В таком случае сильно рекомендую создать где-нибудь папку для пакетов nuget, зарегистрировать её командой `dotnet nuget add source путь_к_папке`, и скидывать туда сами пакеты в формате .nupkg, подключая их стандартным образом.

Это позволит не ломать существующие механизмы контроля версий зависимостей, расширения сборки и т.п.

В будущем таком самодельный репозиторий можно будет заменить полноценным решением.